# Diferencing an autoregressive model

Tags: time-series, arima, autoregressive

By differencing an AR(1) Model could we get an MA(1)?

I mean

$Y_t = U + Y_{t-1} + e_t$

$\Delta Y_t = Y_t - Y_{t-1} = U + E_t = U  + E_t + 0 * E_{t-1}$ >> Meaning MA(1) ?

Comment: By this logic of also counting terms with zero coefficients, you could also make it an MA(7)

Comment: exactly. The exercise requires that i provide proof that the differentiate is a MA(1)  and i'm not sure whehter this is the correct way to do it or there is something else i'm missing

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is clear, you may upvote it and accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 3):

A generic form of an AR(1) process is (the intercept is skipped for simplicity):
$$x_t=\phi x_{t−1}+e_t.$$
Take the same but lagged by one period:
$$x_{t-1}=\phi x_{t-2}+e_{t-1}.$$
Putting the two together, we obtain
$$\Delta x_t:=x_t-x_{t-1}=(\phi x_{t−1}+e_t)-(\phi x_{t-2}+e_{t-1})=\phi(x_{t-1}-x_{t-2})+(e_t-e_{t-1})=\phi \Delta x_{t-1}+e_t-e_{t-1}$$
which yields a special case of ARMA(1,1) with respect to $\Delta x_t$. It is a special case since the MA(1) coefficient is fixed to -1 (that is the coefficient in front of $e_{t-1}$).

This shows that the first difference of an AR(1) process yields an ARMA(1,1) process. Including the intercept would not change the essence (and is left as a homework exercise).